# Using swagger to document api payload

Tags: java, spring, swagger

I have a spring controller which has 2 api's, a POST and PUT which both consume the same api payload/model class: "Pet"

I am trying to document both api's using swagger but I have encountered a problem where I cannot document the Pet class differently for each api. For example I would like to specify a field as mandatory for the POST api but optional for the PUT api.

Any suggestions would be greatly helpful.

Thanks!!

Comment: I came across the same situation, and ended up creating different model classes for different api's. Hope somebody answers with a better alternative.